# Unable to Deserialize a simple enum

Tags: json, java-8, jackson

This is my class User

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "userType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Broker.class, name = "BROKER"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Admin.class, name = "ADMIN")
})
           public   class User {

                protected  String password;
                @Id
                protected String username;
                protected boolean accountNonExpired=true, accountNonBlocked=true, enabled=true, credentialNonExpired=true;
                protected String[] grantedAuthorities;
                protected UserType userType;
                public User(){

                }
         public UserType getUserType() {
                return userType;
            }

            public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
                this.userType = userType;
            }
      @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "password='" + password + '\'' +
                    ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                    ", accountNonExpired=" + accountNonExpired +
                    ", accountNonBlocked=" + accountNonBlocked +
                    ", enabled=" + enabled +
                    ", credentialNonExpired=" + credentialNonExpired +
                    ", grantedAuthorities=" + Arrays.toString(grantedAuthorities) +
                    ", userType=" + userType +
                    '}';
        }
```

It uses an enum as a field of type `UserType

```
    public enum UserType {
        BROKER("BROKER"),ADMIN("ADMIN");

        private static Map<String, UserType> FORMAT_MAP = Stream
                .of(UserType.values())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.value, Function.identity()));

        private final String value;

        UserType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @JsonCreator 
        public static UserType fromString(String string) {
            return Optional
                    .ofNullable(FORMAT_MAP.get(string))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(string));
        }
@JsonValue
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }


    }
```

But `ObjectMapper` is not able to deserialize the `UserType` enum

My Json String :

```
{"password":"135","username":"cooper","accountNonExpired":true,"grantedAuthorities":["ROLE_BROKER"],"userType":"BROKER","brokerName":null,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"enabled":true}
```

This is the code to deserialze :

```
User user = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,User.class);
```

But after desierializing to User object, this is how the user object looks :

```
{password='135', username='cooper', accountNonExpired=true, accountNonBlocked=true, enabled=true, credentialNonExpired=true, grantedAuthorities=[ROLE_BROKER], userType=null}
```

As you can see, userType is null. What is going wrong?

Comment: How does the serialization of `UserType` to a string happen? There is no related code in your class. Besides that, it doesn’t make any sense to maintain a redundant `value` property, containing the same string `name()` will already return and `UserType.valueOf(String)` accepts. Without it, the `FORMAT_MAP` would be obsolete as well.

Comment: @Holger : I edit my UserType class with a JsonValue. It still does not work. I have edit it in the question as well

Comment: It would be helpful to check the property of the deserialized `User` instance, instead of looking at the string representation, to be sure whether this is a deserialization issue or an issue of the creation of the string you’re looking at.

Comment: Why are you explicitly managing deserialization with `@JsonCreator`? You only need to do that when representing the enum with a string other than its `name()`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner It still doesn't work if I remove all the JsonCreator and JsonValue functions

Comment: If you remove all that code and use just the enum, simply as `public enum UserType { BROKER, ADMIN; }`, Jackson will do everything for you. The problem is not in the enum, but somewhere else, i.e. does the `User` class have getters and setters?

Comment: Another possibility is that the `ObjectMapper` is configured to serialize properties as `snake_case` instead of `lowerCamelCase`, in which case it would make sense that the `userType` property were deserialized to `null`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner : yes, it has the getters and setters. I have edited the question to include them

Comment: Yeah, just `public enum UserType { BROKER, ADMIN }` should work. And *if* you think you need explicitly specified representations, you could simply use `public enum UserType { @JsonProperty("BROKER") BROKER, @JsonProperty("ADMIN ") ADMIN }`… As said before, you should check/ clarify  how the string at the end, containing `userType=null` has been created.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner : I am using the OBjectMapper directly using the new() constructor

Comment: @Holger : that string is created by the toString() function of the user class. Edited the question to include that

Comment: @Holger : Btw, I had forgetted to add that userType is also the property used by Jackson to infer the class type. Broker and Admin extend User class. Have edited the User class with the annotations

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner : Btw, I had forgetted to add that userType is also the property used by Jackson to infer the class type. Broker and Admin extend User class. Have edited the User class with the annotations

Answer (score 1):

It works after I changed the `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` to `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`.